# Link DLLs that share the same static library

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, static-libraries

Actually I've the case where two DLLs library_1 and library_2 use functions of a static library vendor.lib, and additionally, library_2 links against library_1 (see diagram below).

[image: dependency diagram]

When I try to build library_2, the linker reports an error to tell me that the symbols of vendor are already defined in library_1. I'm using CMake and Visual Studio 2008 as generator. Note that vendor.lib cannot be touched or modified.

How can I fix those linker errors?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Is it possible these are symbols defined (not just declared) in header files? Can you please paste the full error message, or even better - link to a small self contained repro?